# storing AudioUnits in std::vector in iOS5 with ARC?

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, std, stdvector, objective-c++

I'm building a little synth app/music toy which uses soundFonts. I have a varying number of interactive elements (call them BLOBS) which will have an "instrument" property - a reference to a Synth AudioUnit using one of a number of soundfonts.

I'd like this reference to be a simple int that I can use in order to access the appropriate AudioUnit to play a sound for a particular BLOB.

Is it legit/safe memory-wise in an iOS5 app using ARC to store these AudioUnits in a std::vector? I plan to populate the vector at startup and then just reference the contents as needed.

I define the vector as a property like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) std::vector<AudioUnit> synthUnits;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AudioUnit` is just a pointer so you can store it in a `std::vector` without any problems.

Since [Audio Unit Component Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) is C interface, it doesn't participate in ARC at all.